# How to PIP with Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I am completely new to Android TV but did research quite a bit on my PIP concept's feasibility. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a solution. I am looking to overlay live tv stream on my Android TV app. Hoping the tv remote is still functional to navigate different channels.

[image]

Is this something that can be achieved on Android TV? If so, any pointers on what APIs I should explore? Otherwise any other technology that can help me instead?

Comment: You might be better off with a custom fragment that composes your video view and HTML content into one screen. Using the PIP api is not the same thing you have described. PlutoTV is closer to the example you depicted.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible based on the statement in the documentation:

> Android 7.0 adds support for displaying more than one app at the same
>   time. On handheld devices, two apps can run side-by-side or
>   one-above-the-other in split-screen mode. On TV devices, apps can use
>   picture-in-picture mode to continue video playback while users are
>   interacting with another app.

Just make sure that your app is targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) or higher.